# Rendering Headers for Data Table

Tags: apex, visualforce, header

I have a VF page that renders a datatable when a commandlink is hit. I only want the header's to populate when the commandlink is called. If i put headervalue for my columns its rendered even before I hit the command button. How can I only make it render when the action {!go} is called?

```
   <apex:pageblock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="true">
 <apex:dataTable Value="{!acc}" var="Account" id="accounts" styleClass="list">
      <apex:column headervalue="Name" value="{!Account.Name}"/>
     <apex:column headervalue="Country" value="{!Account.BillingCountry}"/>
```

```
   <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-button" action="{!Go}" reRender=“accounts" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to "render" it (or not) based on some value. Because rendering can be affected by the DOM, make sure you move the reRender target to an already-rendered element:

```
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageBlockSection id="accounts" columns="1" collapsible="true">
<apex:dataTable rendered="{!showAccounts}" Value="{!acc}" var="Account" styleClass="list">
  <apex:column headervalue="Name" value="{!Account.Name}"/>
  <apex:column headervalue="Country" value="{!Account.BillingCountry}"/>
```

Where showAccounts would be:

```
public Boolean showAccounts { get; set; }
```

You'd initialize it as false, then set it to true in your `Go` method:

```
public void go() {
  ...
  showAccounts = true;
  ...
```